# Android AsyncTask with ArrayAdapter gives error "Cannot resolve constructor"

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

Problem with AsyncTask. It does not like my ArrayAdapter:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, result);
```

Fault message: "Cannot resolve constructor"...to long to write.

The code snippet:

```
        private class UpdateListviewWithStringAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList> {
            @Override
            protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... infos) {
                oneLogger = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String info : infos) {
                    Log.d("Haze", info);
                    oneLogger = new ArrayList<String>();
                    oneLogger.add(info);
                }
                return oneLogger;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList... result) {
                listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, result);
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }
```

I have had this ArrayAdapter declaration before in other parts of the code but not in this AsyncTask code.
I'm guessing that I'm trying to do this:

ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects)

Please help me understand why this is wrong:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace "this" with `ActivityName.this`.

Change:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, result);
```

to:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityName.this, R.layout.simplerow, result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList... result
```

I'm not sure if your code will compile but from your snippet this is `ArrayList[]` but written as varargs. you need to use `result[0]` but i think that parameter of **onPostExecute()** method should be only **ArrayList** result and *not array*.

So, it should looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
   listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(<context>, R.layout.simplerow, result);
   listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

*Context* can be passed into class through constructor (this is efficient and clean solution).

**Note:** I recommend to use generics like this: `ArrayList<String>`